# Activate a state in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i want to add a side menu to my project so i added the *menu.html* to my templates and i added a state in my **app.js** :

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/menu',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'menuCtrl'
  })

 .state('ListeUsers', {
    url: '/ListeUsers',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/ListeUsers.html',
          controller: 'UsersCtrl'
        }
      }

  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/ListeUsers');
```

`

my **index.html** body:

`<body ng-app="starter" >
  <ion-nav-view> </ion-nav-view>
  </body>`

it seems that the state ***app*** in not activated when the project is launched.
when i enable server log output i get this at the end:

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

to resolve this problem, i had to define *`ListeUsers`* as a child of *`app`* so the **app.js** becomes like this :

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

   .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
  })

  .state('app.ListeUsers', {
    url: '/ListeUsers',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/ListeUsers.html',
          controller: 'UsersCtrl'
        }
      }

  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/ListeUsers');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default activate you should do like this or more info give link below.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/menu');
```

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router